# Programmatically get the link a cached webpage in bing

Tags: bing

Well, i'm trying to recover a website from google/bing cache. I can do it with google but it limits the request like 400 per day, so trying bing.
In google if i search "cache:sitelink" it redirects to

> http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3A***sitelink***&oq=cache%3A ***sitelink***&aqs=chrome.0.57l2j58j60l2j61&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

then i can manipulate the *sitelink* url using a loop like www.example.com/post$i.html where $i = 20000 to 24000

but when i tried to do same with bing cache, i saw http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=........d=[A BIG ID]....... so the url of the site is not in the link, so i cant manipulate it. also the "cache:sitelink" shortcut doesn't work in bing. Is there or shortcut for bing like google ?

Comment: It does not look like Bing wants anyone to link to these pages directly.